# How to Split a String and Iterate in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm new to Redshift and I stumbled across a scenario wherein my procedure, I wanted to split a string and iterate it through and do some manipulations in it. I know redshift doesn't support arrays and I want to know how to achieve this in redshift

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE example(value IN varchar) AS $$
 BEGIN
    --value = 'FIRST, SECOND, THIRD' -> I want to split the string using a comma and iterate through one by one and do some manipulations.
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Can Someone guide me through it?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: The answer from John is correct but since you are new to Redshift I'll give a recommendation.  If your data is large that you need to operate on, be sure that you need a stored procedure and cannot perform the same operation using straight SQL.  You see stored procedures offer great flexibility invoking them on large data can be slow.  So if you can get by without stored procedures your large data execution time will be better in Redshift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a loop of incrementing values, and call [`SPLIT_PART()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html), passing in the loop value.

> If part is larger than the number of string portions, `SPLIT_PART` returns an empty string.

Therefore, you would stop the loop if an empty string is returned.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TABLE bar3 AS (
    SELECT '1,2,300' AS data
    union
    select '5,6,7' as data);

with bar3 as (select split_to_array(data, ',') as sp from bar3)
select p from bar3 b, b.sp p;
```

This is PariQL unnesting syntax for Redshift. 6 rows for 6 numbers.